# Can't navigate to another screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am having a bit of trouble with react-navigation

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Image} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from "./src/screens/Home.js";
import InvitePage from './src/screens/InvitePage.js';
import WelcomePage from './src/screens/WelcomePage.js';
import NamePage from './src/screens/NamePage.js';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function LogoTitle() {
  return (
    <Image
      style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
      source={require("./assets/Appicon.png")}
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  const [userName,setuserName]=useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => { 
      async function getName(){
              try {
                const result= await AsyncStorage.getItem('namekey')
                setuserName(result);
                setLoading(false);
              }
              catch(e) {
                setLoading(false);
              } 
        }
      getName();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
      return (
        <></>
      )
    }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {userName ? 
        (<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} 
        options={{
          headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} /> ,
          headerStyle: {
            height: 120,
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}/>):(
          <>
        <Stack.Screen name="WelcomePage" component={WelcomePage} 
        options={{ 
          title: 'Welcome',
          headerStyle: {backgroundColor:'#fff',height: 100 },
      }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="NamePage" component={NamePage} 
        options={{ 
          title: 'Welcome',
          headerStyle: {backgroundColor:'#fff',height: 100 },
      }}
      
        />
         </>
         )}
        <Stack.Screen name="InvitePage" component={InvitePage} 
        options={{ 
          title: 'Invite',
          headerStyle: {backgroundColor:'#fff',height: 100 },
      }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my app.js.Here, I am reading a file using async storage and then i decide based on that which screen i want to navigate to but the problem is when i go to my name setup page and after saving the name to async storage I can't navigate to home page for some reason
i am getting this error:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

i think maybe home page is not getting initialized in this code?
This is my namePage:

```
async function next(){
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('namekey', name)
      console.log("done")
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("errorNamePage")
    }
    navigation.navigate("Home");
  }


return(

  <View style={styles.headerview}>
    <Text style={{fontSize:30,marginTop:250,fontFamily:"AzoSans-Medium",marginLeft:30,marginRight:30}}>Please enter your name</Text>
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Name"
        onChangeText={name => setName(name)}
        defaultValue={name}
        onSubmitEditing={()=>next()}
        autoCorrect = {false}
      />
    <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop: 150}} onPress={()=> next()}>
    <Image source={require('../../assets/welcome-next.png')} style={{width:100, height: 100,marginLeft:150}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  );

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you used in navigator probably separates `NamePage` and `Home`, so they are not accessible for each other I guess. Once you get to Name page, userName must be a truthy value to navigate to `Home`

If you tell about your intention more, people here can show you a simpler solution.